# Cannot read data from android dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog

I am trying to read data from a dialog (signup page) shown below:
[image]

**The Code is:**

```
private void loginAndSignupDialog() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SelectServiceActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_login);
    dialog.setTitle("Login");
    dialog.findViewById(R.id.login_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final String username = ((EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.username)).getText().toString();
            final String password = ((EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.password)).getText().toString();
            validateUser(username, password, dialog);
        }
    });
    dialog.findViewById(R.id.to_signup_page).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SelectServiceActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_signup);
            dialog.setTitle("Signup");
            dialog.findViewById(R.id.signup).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    final String email = ((EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
                    final String password = ((EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.password)).getText().toString();
                    final String confirmPassword = ((EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.confirm_password)).getText().toString();
                    final String mobileNo = ((EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.mobile_number)).getText().toString();
                    if (password.equals(confirmPassword)) {
                        registerUser(email, password, mobileNo);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(SelectServiceActivity.this, "Two passwords are not same.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

**I am getting "Null pointer Exception" at these lines :**

```
final String email = ((EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
                        final String password = ((EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.password)).getText().toString();
                        final String confirmPassword = ((EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.confirm_password)).getText().toString();
                        final String mobileNo = ((EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.mobile_number)).getText().toString();
```

The scenario is I am moving from login dialog to signup dialog page by clicking in **SIGNUP** text on login page shown below :

[image]

I am getting data at login page with no error but getting null pointer exception on signup page attributes.

**Signup Dialog XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="20sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    tools:context="in.co.servicedeal.app.SignupActivity">
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/sd_logo" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/signup_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/confirm_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/confirmPassword"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/mobile_number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/mobileNumber"
        android:inputType="phone" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            app:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/serviceAggrement" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/signup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="@dimen/card_elevation"
        android:text="@string/signUp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

**Login Dialog XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="20sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="in.co.servicedeal.app.LoginActivity">
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/sd_logo" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/userName" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25sp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/dontHaveAcct" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/to_signup_page"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5sp"
            android:text="@string/signUp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
</android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Please suggest!

Comment: paste dialog xml  code

Comment: Put error stacktrace

Comment: Facing same problem ?? show xml please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NullPointerException is thrown when an application attempts to use an
>   object reference that has the null value .

1. You are Opening **`new Dialog from Parent`** .
2. Check **`getText().toString()`** are **null or NOT** .
3. Make sure you set Proper **`findViewById(R.id.`**

You should try with

```
final Dialog dialog_SignUP = new Dialog(SelectServiceActivity.this);
dialog_SignUP.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_signup);
dialog_SignUP.setTitle("Signup");
dialog_SignUP.findViewById(R.id.signup).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final String email = ((EditText) dialog_SignUP.findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
                final String password = ((EditText) dialog_SignUP.findViewById(R.id.password)).getText().toString();
                final String confirmPassword = ((EditText) dialog_SignUP.findViewById(R.id.confirm_password)).getText().toString();
                final String mobileNo = ((EditText) dialog_SignUP.findViewById(R.id.mobile_number)).getText().toString();
                if (password.equals(confirmPassword)) {
                    registerUser(email, password, mobileNo);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SelectServiceActivity.this, "Two passwords are not same.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
dialog_SignUP.show();
```

Comment: You mean I should open a new dialog "signup" with in "login" ?

Comment: @ShamimAhmad you can if no problem

Comment: Okay, Here I have a new thing, The very first-time login dialog will open, if the user is not registered, he will move to signup dialog by clicking on SIGNUP text on login dialog page, it the user has moved to signup dialog and he remembers he is a registered used he will move to login page by clicking on LOGIN text on signup dialog.

Comment: @ShamimAhmad You should pass those values .

Comment: How, It is different with what I am doing in my code above?

Comment: Creating new  dialog (signup) from existing dialog (login) like this "final Dialog dialog_SignUP = new Dialog(SelectServiceActivity.this)" worked for

Answer (score 0):

Your email,password,confirmPassword,mobilno fields are null.

Try this:

```
final String email = ((EditText)v dialog.findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
final String password = ((EditText)v dialog.findViewById(R.id.password)).getText().toString();

final String confirmPassword = ((EditText)v dialog.findViewById(R.id.confirm_password)).getText().toString();

final String mobileNo = ((EditText)v dialog.findViewById(R.id.mobile_number)).getText().toString();
```

Comment: what is "v" next to (EditText) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your interface `DialogOnClickListener` and put there filled `Bundle`